# Angular jqLite .find() will not return any inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

EDIT: So it seems to be an issue with selectors? Does jqLite not support selectors or some reduced version of them?

find('input') and find('button') will return results but if I try to filter it with a ":first" or something then it returns no results.

---

I can't seem to get jqLite's find() to return any child inputs of my div.

I have a $watch on a boolean function that my ng-show uses. So when this div becomes visible I want to apply focus on the div element and then find the first input descendant and focus on that.

example div element that the directive watches:

```
<div myDirective="function()">
    text and stuff
    <button>
    <another button>
</div>

<div myDirective="function()">
    <input>
</div>
```

this is my helper function in my directive:

```
function highlightAndFocus(node) {
      // focus the div
      node.focus();
      // get angular's jqlite wrapped element
      var task = angular.element(node);
      task.addClass('highlight');

      // these return empty statements
      console.log(task.find('input:first'));
      console.log(task.find('button:visible:not("#cancel"):first'));
}
```

The angular documentation says it finds only by tag name but isn't that what "input" and "button" are?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

What's going on here? It seems silly to include jquery just for this one usecase when it seems like it should be supported. I'm printing the var task and I can see the input child elements in the web console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQlite is not the same thing as jQuery. ***If*** jQuery is available on the page, Angular will use it, but if it isn't, jQlite is used instead.
[The docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) clearly say that jQlite's `.find()` only supports lookup by tag names, it doesn't to work with additional selectors (like `:first`).

You can use the standard DOM APIs instead, namely [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), if you really need it.

Comment: I guess I assumed selectors were a base feature. So I have two buttons in these divs, a yes and a no. If I search for "button" then I'll get two results, is the only way to focus on the "yes" button to add id="yes" to those buttons and then search on find('button yes')?

Comment: @MilanNovaković When Angular was first conceived, jQuery was still _very_ prevalent in the web development community. Angular didn't look to replicate jQuery's functionality, but offer an alternative approach to development structure altogether. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) for a more broad explanation.

Comment: So how can I find my input when there's multiple results?

Also something is funky about all this. I've had another directive where find with selectors seems to be working. In particular I'm using :visible:not("#cancel") and it only grabs the continue button that I wanted, when there are a dozen defined but are just hidden with ng-show.